# Heroku does not take a gem in compilation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

rails 3.2.13

It seems like my heroku app suddenly stopped pre-compiling.

When i do git push heroku master, it finishes with no errors.
Also, when I do heroku rake db:migrate, everything seems fine.
But When I try loading the site or running "heroku run rails c", I get an application error.
In the logs i see that it does not recognize my 'gmaps4rails' gem. (Which is not just in development).
This worked perfectly fine before my last major commit, so I must have broken something, I just don't know what.
The site runs great in development.

Tried rebuilding the heroku db in every way I could find, but with no results.

here is the heroku logs dump:

> 2013-10-24T22:09:02.244984+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by xxx@yahoo.com 
>   2013-10-24T22:09:10.239594+00:00 heroku[run.8498]: Awaiting client  
>   2013-10-24T22:09:10.319099+00:00 heroku[run.8498]: Starting process with command `bundle  exec rake db:migrate`  
>   2013-10-24T22:09:11.463254+00:00 heroku[run.8498]: State changed from starting to up  
>   2013-10-24T22:09:15.090835+00:00 heroku[run.8498]: Process exited with status 0  
>   2013-10-24T22:09:15.109542+00:00 heroku[run.8498]: State changed from up to complete  
>   2013-10-24T22:15:48.976455+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>    crashed to starting
>   2013-10-24T22:15:56.503853+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 51113`  
>   2013-10-24T22:15:59.948210+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick  
>   2013-10-24T22:15:59.948210+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.13 application starting in production on "http://0.0.0.o:51113"  
>   2013-10-24T22:15:59.948210+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach  
>   2013-10-24T22:15:59.948210+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server  
>   2013-10-24T22:15:59.948210+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by  DATABASE_URL  
>   2013-10-24T22:16:00.937338+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'  <br>
>   2013-10-24T22:16:00.937338+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/models/project.rb:52:in`'  
>   2013-10-24T22:16:00.937338+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/models/project.rb:29:in `<top (required)>'  <br>
>   2013-10-24T22:16:00.937338+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in`block in require'  
>   2013-10-24T22:16:00.936345+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting  
>   2013-10-24T22:16:00.937338+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'  <br>
>   2013-10-24T22:16:00.937338+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in`load_missing_constant'  
>   2013-10-24T22:16:00.937338+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:55:in `method_missing': undefined method`acts_as_gmappable' for # (NoMethodError)
>   201

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Were any of your changes to your Gemfile? You may have created some kind of version incompatibility. Also, take a look at `git blame` to see what changed between pushes: https://help.github.com/articles/using-git-blame-to-trace-changes-in-a-file

Comment: I did not change the gemfile. However, I had to reset and recreate the db.  could it be a problem of db? Could it be that the acts_as_gmappable is not recognized because the class (project) was not built correctly?  Is there a way to see the production db state?

Answer (score 0):

In order to see the state of your database to see how that might affect your application, try

`heroku pg:psql` (assuming Postgres)

And run your SQL commands from there. See [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-psql) for more.

I was also able to connect my IDE to my databases on Heroku. I am using RubyMine, so it was a matter of using the right JDBC URL to make that happen.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I tried it, but it doesn't recognize this command.  i get   !    The local psql command could not be located
 !    For help installing psql, see http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-p
ostgresql

Comment: Do you have a local instance? As the link I sent points out, "You must have PostgreSQL installed on your system to use heroku pg:psql." https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#local-setup

Comment: I'm having problems installing it, but I tried something else in the meantime.  I went back to a previously working model (in a new work area) and created a new heroku repo.  I did the following commands: git clone (for model) -> bundle install -> heroku create -> git push heroku master -> heroku rake db:migrate .  Now I get the same crash, but this time it tells me in the log app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:55:in `method_missing': undefined method `acts_as_gmappable' for Project(**Table doesn't exist**):Class (NoMethodError)